# reactjs-toolbox radiobutton group does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-toolbox

in my react app I use radio buttons with this code:

```
 <RadioGroup name='steptype' className={css.ProcessStepRadioButtons} value={this.state.stepsData[stepNumber].stepType}
                                onChange={(value, event) => {
                                    this.changeInputOptionHandlerProcessStep(value, "stepType", stepNumber)
                                }}>
                        <RadioButton label={<T value='processes.new.processStepTypeDuty'/>} value={1} />
                        <RadioButton label={<T value='processes.new.processStepTypeVariable'/>} value={2}/>
                        <RadioButton label={<T value='processes.new.processStepTypeOptioanal'/>} value={3}/>
                    </RadioGroup>
```

and this handler:

```
export function changeInputOptionHandlerProcessStep(value, field, step) {
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    stepsData: prevState.stepsData.map((currentStep, i) => {
        if (i === step) {
            return {
                ...currentStep,
                [field]: value
            }
        }
        return currentStep
    })
}), () => {
    console.log("New state in ASYNC callback:", this.state.stepsData);
} );
}
```

State is set properly, but the radio buttons does not switch visually,

what could be the problem in this case?

thanks

UPDATE consolelog of this.state.stepsData

[image]

Update consolelog of this.state.stepsData right bevore render[image]

Comment: I believe you need to pass `checked` attribute to your `RadioButton` component.

Comment: and how could that look like? thats the example from react-toolbox http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/radio_group they don't pass it

Comment: Code snippet will be great to ease debugging your code.

Comment: can you post the code that results from `console.log("New state in ASYNC callback:", this.state.stepsData);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your state design is not adequate for the `RadioGroup` component.

This is a [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) behind the scenes, so the radio button selected is imposed at all times by `RadioGroup`'s `value` prop. I don't know how you are initialising the component (meaning default selection), **but its `value` should always belong to one of the `value`s of the single `RadioButton` components**, meaning that `this.state.stepsData[stepNumber].stepType` should be 1, 2 o 3.

`stepType` sounds to me (making assumptions here) like a string rather than a number, so it may be the initialisation is wrong and the component automatically resorts to the first radio button as the default selected.

Taking that into account, your *substate* for controlling this group of radio buttons should be a number (1, 2 or 3). Then, your handler `changeInputOptionHandlerProcessStep` will receive the new selection (new number) as first argument and you can just set the state with the new value. It would be something like:

```
<RadioGroup 
    name='steptype' 
    className={css.ProcessStepRadioButtons} 
    value={this.state.stepNumber} // initialised to 1, 2 or 3
    onChange={(value, event) => {this.changeInputOptionHandlerProcessStep(value, "stepType", stepNumber)}}
>
    <RadioButton label={<T value='processes.new.processStepTypeDuty'/>} value={1} />
    <RadioButton label={<T value='processes.new.processStepTypeVariable'/>} value={2}/>
    <RadioButton label={<T value='processes.new.processStepTypeOptioanal'/>} value={3}/>
</RadioGroup>

function changeInputOptionHandlerProcessStep(newValue) {
     this.setState({ stepNumber: newValue });
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Problem is that the stepNumber is in an Array I think. The logic I have above works but viually they don't change the bullets.

Comment: added a screenshot of this.state.stepsData above

Comment: Could you tell me what's the value of `stepNumber` initially, what's the default radio button selected and also which radio button do you click on that trigger the listener and the new state you screenshoted?

Comment: stepNumber is initially = 0 default radiobutton is the first one wth value 1
in state the stepType is set correctly when I click the second one in stepType there is now a 2

Comment: ok, it would be great if you could provide a snapshot of your state before the handler is trigger, some `console.log` at the beginning of `render()`

Comment: Actually, how are you updating `stepNumber` after the handler code fired? I am guessing that's part of your state as well, something like `state.stepNumber` ?

Comment: from this the stepNumber comes. `const stepNumber = this.state.stepsData.length - 1;` stepNumber is not in state

Comment: I can't spot any errors, excepting for the fact that the 2 screenshots are inconsistent, after the trigger the length of the array is 2 and before is 1 and the state goes through a `map` operation, which doesn't change the length of the array. I am curious about how your handler is defined, you are referencing it using `this`, but then is defined as a separated function that you export (in a different file). Probably if you could paste the whole component code it would help

Comment: The length ist because in the First Screenshot Im have two steps and in the Second one I habe Only one

Comment: I've written my own radio buttons that sovled the problem